# Laravel Multiple requirements for relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an Item table, Meta table and a Item_Meta table which has all meta records for Items. One Item has many Meta records.

Item_meta has the following columns: 
Item_id | Meta_id | Value

Lets say I have a requirements: 
Requirement 1 - ['Meta_id' => 1, 'value' => 'new']
Requirement 2 - ['Meta_id' => 3, 'value' => 'LCD']

I need to build a query get all items, which have meta_id with id 1 equal to new, and meta_id with id 3 equal to LCD.

So if an item does not have one of this metas (or one of metas has wrong value) it should not be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter your models on relation's attributes using Eloquent's **whereHas()** method. In your case the following code should do the trick:

```
$items = Item::whereHas('metas', function($query) {
  $query->where('Meta_id', 1);
  $query->where('value', 'new);
})
->whereHas('metas', function($query) {
  $query->where('Meta_id', 3);
  $query->where('value', 'LCD);
})
->get();
```

I assumed that your item->meta relation is called **metas**.

You could also use another form of using **whereHas()** where you provide number of matching related records. The code will be a bit more complex but it will result in less subselects in the executed query:

```
$items = Item::whereHas('metas', function($query) {
  $query->where('Meta_id', 1);
  $query->where('value', 'new);
  $query->orWhere(function($query2) {
    $query2->where('Meta_id', 3);
    $query2->where('value', 'LCD);
  };
}, '=', 2)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the first approach from the previous answer before asking the question, but it failed so I thought it had a mistake. But after seeing and that answer it seemed that I don't understand something. So I digged inside of Laravel Eloquent internals and here is what I found:

Eloquent Build class "::where" method changes $this->query property before returning the instance. Here is the code:

```
public function where($column, $operator = null, $value = null, $boolean = 'and')
{
    if ($column instanceof Closure) {
        $query = $this->model->newQueryWithoutScopes();

        call_user_func($column, $query);

        $this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);
    } else {
        call_user_func_array([$this->query, 'where'], func_get_args());
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Take notice of "$this->query->addNestedWhereQuery($query->getQuery(), $boolean);" on the 6th line.

The Builder class "::whereHas" method does not modify "$this->query" property.

```
public function whereHas($relation, Closure $callback, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)
{
    return $this->has($relation, $operator, $count, 'and', $callback);
}
```

So, what it has to do with my problem. I have created a query like this:

```
$query = Item::where('active',1);
```

Then I added the conditions:

```
if($meta){
    $query->whereHas('metas', function($query) {
        $query->where('Meta_id', 1);
        $query->where('value', 'new);
    })
    ->whereHas('metas', function($query) {
      $query->where('Meta_id', 3);
      $query->where('value', 'LCD);
    })
 }
```

and then query was performed:

```
$query->get();
```

The mistake was related to ::whereHas method, what I had to do was assign whereHas result to the variable:

```
 if($meta){
    $query = $query->whereHas('metas', function($query) {
        $query->where('Meta_id', 1);
        $query->where('value', 'new);
    })
    ->whereHas('metas', function($query) {
      $query->where('Meta_id', 3);
      $query->where('value', 'LCD);
    })
 }
```

So thats all. Always check with internals if something works unexpectadely